# Initialize all hashes with a default_proc

Tags: ruby, hash, initialization

I wanted to extend the Hash class so that all hashes get same `default_proc` when they're created. So I put this in my file:

```
class Hash
  def initialize
    self.default_proc = proc { |hash, key| raise NameError, "#{key} is not allowed" }
  end
end
```

This works fine if I use this syntax

```
h = Hash.new
```

but not if I use

```
h = {}
```

Playing with it, it seems that the latter syntax doesn't call initialize.  Is there an "iron-clad" way to achieve setting the `default_proc` for all hashes?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could just intercept []

```
class Hash
  alias realGet []
  def [](x)
    t = realGet(x)
    if t == nil
      puts 'intercepted'
    end
    t
  end
end
```

Comment: cool!  that never would have occurred to me.  the good news is, it'll be a looooooong time before I'm bored with ruby. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `{}` won't call the `initialize` method, as you can't pass a block to `{}`:

```
# This will issue an error
h = {}{#some block code}
```

However you still can pass blocks to the new method:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| raise NameError, "#{key} is not allowed" }
```